# jmeter server communication issues

Tags: jmeter

I am running jmeter on a powerful server in distributed mode and trying connect to it from the GUI on my local machine.  Everything works OK and when i select remote server run and tail the jmeter logs on the server it goes through the starting tests...running test.... etc but it then says connection refused on *** .**.**.***

This is my local machine so I suspect that the tests are being run on the server and then the results are being piped back to the client and this is where the problems are.

So I have one way communication where my client GUI can send commands to the server but the server cannot send them back to my client PC

Any ideas what might be going on?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think the idea behind jmeter in your use-case would be to skip the "native" gui that interacts with the server. you will have to implement jmeter samplers that act just as the gui would - this includes e.g. handshakes etc.

for example, a session-id would be kept alive and passed from sampler to sampler to simulate the frontend..